# LaTeX: Inline image, but preserving line height

Tags: graphics, inline, line, height

I'd like to include an inline image (to typeset hieroglyphic inscriptions) but I don't want it to stretch the line height, even if the image is too tall to fit. I don't mind it colliding with the line above and below and overlapping text, but the line height should be preserved at all costs.

Here is an example of incorrect line spacing:

[image]

The code used to produce this is

```
\raisebox{-0.75em}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{lorem_chickens.eps}}
```

Now, this example is grossly exaggerated to demonstrate the issue. In actual usage, I would increase the line spacing and perhaps reduce the size of the image. However, if I could make the spacing work (no matter how ugly it looks) even on an extreme example like this, I could also make it work with reasonable line spacing and image size.

If I were doing this in HTML/CSS I would set a huge negative top margin on the image (`<img href="lorem_chickens.svg" style="margin-top: -1000px" />`) and the image would be overlapping with the text (which is, in my case, desired behaviour). But I don't know how to do this in LaTeX. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you enclose the code in `\smash{...}`, the height and depth will be suppressed.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Please post it so I can mark it as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please post a minimal working example with your question that demonstrates your problem.  Otherwise, I see it's already solved; so be sure to accept the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\smash{...}` suppresses the height and depth of its argument, which will, in the OP's case, allow oversized images to be inserted without breaking the default line spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\smash{\includegraphics[height=15pt]{example-image}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach is to force the image by way of scaling, to fit in the allowed space.  Here, `\scalerel*` indicates to scale the image to the vertical footprint of `\strut` (the default allotted line space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\scalerel*{\includegraphics{example-image}}{\strut}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]